# Setting NSScrollView Contents to Top Left Instead of Bottom Left When Document Swapping

Tags: cocoa, coordinates, nsview, nsscrollview

I had one of my colleagues come to me today with a problem of how can he load or view-swap a `documentView` of an `NSScrollView` so that the loaded view appears to fix to the top-left corner instead of the bottom-let corner.

He had spent a while searching the web and floundering and didn't have a solution despite reading the documentation at Apple, on StackOverflow and various other places.

Here's the issue piece-by-piece:

In Interface Builder drag an `NSScrollView` into the project.
Also in Interface Builder drag two custom views into the project and add some textfields, buttons etc.

Create a controller class (e.g. myController) with the following `IBOutlet`s:

- `IBOutlet NSScrollView * myScrollView`
- `IBOutlet NSView * myCustomView1`
- `IBOutlet NSView * myCustomView2`

Connect the outlets to the controls in Interface Builder.

Create an `NSView` subclass to flip the `documentView`:

```
@implementation myFlippedView

-(id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    // Drawing code here.
}

-(BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}
```

Select the `documentView`of the `NSScrollView` in Interface Builder and make it a subclass of `myFlippedView`. In Interface Builder you would select the NSScrollView and then click in it again to get to the `documentView`, or change the IB Library to show a tree view and select the child custom view of the `NSScrollView`.

In the `myController` class swap the views with the following methods:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

    [myScrollView setDocumentView:myCustomView1];
}

-(IBAction)swapViews:(id)sender {

    if ([myScrollView documentView] == myCustomView1) {

        [myScrollView setDocumentView:myCustomView2];

    } else {

        [myScrollView setDocumentView:myCustomView1];

    }
}
```

Finally hook up a button in your project to the action `swapViews`, build and run.

The problem is that the coordinates were not being resolved as was expected with the isFlipped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a simple, but apparently often overlooked reason for this.

Although `isFlipped` is subclassing the custom view in Interface Builder, the documentView is getting replaced on the view swap, the first of which gets used on `awakeFromNib`.

The solution is to subclass myCustomClass1 and myCustomClass2 to the myFlippedView class.

Do this and test it and you will notice that the views now appear in the top left of the scroll view. It has, however, created a new problem. All of the content in the custom view is now laid out from bottom to top (because by default all `NSView` layouts are from bottom left, so flipping also flips their coordinates).

Fortunately there is another easy fix for this problem. Read on :-)

In Interface Builder, highlight all the controls in `myCustomView1` and from the `Layout` menu, select Embed Objects In --> Custom View. Resize as you need to, do the same for myCustomView2 and rebuild.

Voila. An `NSScrollView` with the content view swapping and appearing at the top-left of the scroll view instead of the bottom left.

Comment: Or you could go the simpler route and just make the swapped views a subview of the myFlippedView instead of making them the document view.

Comment: This introduces a new issue however. If you make the scroll view smaller than the document view by resizing a window, it pins to the bottom of the view instead to the top. As a user you would rather expect the latter.

Comment: @Rafael did you find a solution to this ? I also want the background image stuck to the top.

Comment: I did not investigate further into this issue.

Comment: Setting `origin.y` to 0 in the flipped view subclass in `setFrame:` did the trick for me. It’s ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 6):

To correctly make the `documentView` initially align to the top of the scrollview AND to also *pin* it to the top when the `documentView` is smaller than it's clipview, this is what works for me:

1 – In Interface Builder enclose all controls in your documentView in a *custom* `NSView` instance. (NOT a flipped view)

2 – Create an `NSView` subclass to be used for the `documentView`, and override these methods:

```
- (BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}
- (void)resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:(NSSize)oldSize {
CGFloat superViewHeight = self.superview.frame.size.height, height = self.frame.size.height;
    if(superViewHeight>height) {
        [self setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(self.frame.origin.x, superViewHeight-height)];
    }
}
```

The subclassed view should be the scrollViews' `documentView` which contains second (normal) NSView that contains all controls.